# Avoid / set character set conversion /encoding for std::cout / std::cerr

Tags: c++, libstdc++

**General question**

Is there a possibility to avoid character set conversion when writing to  `std::cout` / `std::cerr`?
I do something like

```
std::cout << "Ȋ'ɱ ȁ ȖȚƑ-8 Șțȓȉɳɠ (in UTF-8 encoding)" << std::endl;
```

And I want the output to be written to the console maintaining the UTF-8 encoding (my console uses UTF-8 encoding, but my C++ Standard Library, GNUs `libstdc++`, doesn't think so for some reason).

If there's no possibility to forbid character encoding conversion: Can I set `std::cout` to use UTF-8, so it hopefully figures out itself that no conversion is needed?

**Background**

I used the Windows API function `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` to set my console's encoding to UTF-8.
The problem seems to be that UTF-8 does not match the code page typicallly used for my system's locale and `libstdc++` therefore sets up `std::cout` with the default ANSI code page instead of correctly recognizing the switch.

---

**Edit:** Turns out I misinterpreted the issue and the solution is actually a lot simpler (or not...).

The `"Ȋ'ɱ ȁ ȖȚƑ-8 Șțȓȉɳɠ (in UTF-8 encoding)"` was just meant as a placeholder (and I shouldn't have used it as it has hidden the actual issue).

In my real code the "UTF-8 string" is a [`Glib::ustring`](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html), and those are by definition UTF-8 encoded.
However I did not realize that the output operator `<<` was [defined in glibmm](https://github.com/GNOME/glibmm/blob/master/glib/glibmm/ustring.cc#L1430) in a way that forces character set conversion.
It uses `g_locale_from_utf8()` internally which in turn uses [`g_get_charset()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#g-get-charset) to determine the target encoding.

Unfortunately the documentation for `g_get_charset()` states

> On Windows the character set returned by this function is the so-called system default ANSI code-page. That is the character set used by the "narrow" versions of C library and Win32 functions that handle file names. It might be different from the character set used by the C library's current locale.

which simply means that glib will neither care for the C locale I set nor will it attempt to determine the encoding my console actually uses and basically makes it impossible to use many glib functions to create UTF-8 output. (As a matter of fact this also means that this issue has the exact same cause as the issue that triggered my other question: [Force UTF-8 encoding in glib's "g_print()"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43927373/2514664)).

I'm currently considering this a bug in glib (or a serious limitation at best) and will probably open a report in the issue tracker for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6954596/560648?

Comment: `setlocale()` will only affect the C locale. C++ stream IO functions unfortunately won't be affected by that.

The C++ equivalent would be `std::locale::global()`, but a) as far as I understand it won't modify existing stream objects, b) it's unclear to me how I could set an encoding with it, and c) libstdc++ has limited locale support on anything other than Linux (it basically only knows `std::locale::classic()` on Windows).

Comment: Codepages in windows are only for 8bit characters.... they don't cover well UTF.

Comment: Which is why I set the console encoding to UTF-8... Works really well (at least on Windows 10), with the exception that many libraries just blindly assume Windows was stupid (honestly not the worst assumption) and could only handle one of those limited code pages.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong side, as you are talking about a string literal, included in your source code (and not input from your keyboard), and for that to work properly you have to tell the compiler which encoding is being used for all those characters (I think the first c++ spec that mentions non-ascii charsets is c++11)

As you are using actually the UTF charset, you should have to encode all them in at least a `wchar_t` to be considered as such, or to agree in the translator (probably this is what happens) that UTF chars will be UTF-8 encoded, when used as string literals.  This will commonly mean that they will be printed as UTF-8 and, if you use a UTF-8 compliant console device, they will be printed ok, without any other problem.

I know there's a **gcc** option to specify the encoding used in string literals for a source file, and there should be another in **clang** also.  Check the documentation and probably this will solve any issues.  But the best thing to be portable, is not to depend on the codeset or use one like ISO-10646 (but know that full utf coverage is not only utf-8, utf-8 is **only** a way to encode UTF chars, and as so, it's only a way to represent UTF characters)

Another issue, is that C++11 doesn't refer to the UTF consortium standard, but to the ISO counterpart (ISO-10646, I think), both are similar, but not equal, and the character encodings are similar, but not equal (the codesize of the ISO is 32 bit while the Unicode consortium's is 21 bit, for example).  These and other differences between them make some tricks to go in C++ and produce problems when one is thinking in strict Unicode.

Of course, to output correct strings on a UTF-8 terminal, you have to encode UTF codes to utf-8 format before sending them to the terminal.  This is true, even if you have already them encoded as utf-8 in a string object.  If you say they are *already utf-8* then no conversion is made at all... but if you don't say, the normal consideration is that you are using normal utf codes (but limiting to 8bit codes), limiting yourself to eight bit codes, and encoding them to utf-8 before printing... this leads to encoding errors (double encoding) as something like `ú` (unicode code `\u00fa`) should be encoded in utf-8 as the character sequence `{ 0xc3, 0xba };`, but if you don't say the string literal is indeed in utf-8, both characters will be handled as the two characters codes for `Â`(`\u00c3`) and `º`(`\u00ba`) characters, and will be recoded as `{ 0xc3, 0x83, 0xc2, 0xba };` that will show them incorrectly.  This is very common error and you should probably have seen it when some encoding is done incorrectly.  Source for the samples [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice write up... It didn't solve my original issue, as I misinterpreted the behavior (see edit to my question) but I certainly learned a lot from it!

Comment: But the problem in your case is that Windows doesn't properly support utf-8 encoding (no codepage available to support it)