# Force UTF-8 encoding in glib's "g_print()"

Tags: c, gtk, glib

**Short question:** Is there a way to force glib's `g_print()` to use UTF-8 encoding?

The problem I hit is that `g_print()` [seems to do character set conversion](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/0d28ee458f1847b3c7f3ed810b28b9a988ece40a/glib/gmessages.c#L2886) based on the return value of [`g_get_charset()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#g-get-charset). Now the documentation unfortunately mentions

> On Windows the character set returned by this function is the so-called system default ANSI code-page.

However nowadays modern consoles are available: MSYS consoles typically support (and use) UTF-8 by default and even the default Windows console can be set to use UTF-8 encoding.

Now it seems Windows has finally catched up and glib is limiting me to a 255 character code page after all???
I'd simply switch my code to plain `printf` but unfortunately `g_print` is called in many locations from inside glib and gtk libraries, as well as their C++ bindings glibmm and gtkmm and I obviously have no easy possibility to change anything about that short of patching and compiling glib myself, so I really hope there's a solution to that.

---

*Note: Just saw the part calling `local_glib_print_func()` in the definition of `g_print()`. Aynbody knows what this is about and if I could exploit it for my purposes?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in fact I gave myself the correct hint:

While investigating the *Note* in my question I discovered the function [`g_set_print_handler`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Warnings-and-Assertions.html#g-set-print-handler) which allows to create an arbitrary handler that replaces the default mechanism and also circumvents the character conversion.

The following minimal print handler let's me print to the console with `g_print()` avoiding any unwanted character set conversion:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <glib.h>

void g_print_no_convert(const gchar *buf)
{
    fputs(buf, stdout);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    g_set_print_handler(g_print_no_convert);
    g_print("UTF-8 string");

    return 0;
}
```

Note: Writing UTF-8 strings obviously only works if your console's encoding is in fact UTF-8.

---

On Windows you can set your console's encoding to UTF-8 either manually by executing the command `chcp 65001` or programmatically with the following API functions

```
#include <windows.h>

// temporarily switch console encoding to UTF8
const unsigned int initial_cp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

{...} // printing

// switch back to initial console encoding
SetConsoleOutputCP(initial_cp);
```

This approach easily allows to print UTF-8 strings to the Windows console (tested with the default console as well as MSYS2's terminal on Windows 10).

Comment: That's interesting (your edit) -- I'm writing a (tiny) cross-platform framework and already decided for `UTF8` as internal string representation, so this could be easier than my first idea to do conversions for `stdio` on win32 -- I already have to convert everything from/to user32.dll / comctl32.dll. Do you know in which version the windows console started to support `CP_UTF8` output?

Comment: No, but I'd certainly be interested too... (I'm afraid I also can't test as on an XP machine I just tried my MSYS2-compiled test program won't even run - even if it's just a dummy executable without content)

At the very least Windows XP allows to set `chcp 65001` and it certainly changes something. However I suspect that XP did not yet have a Unicode console font, so even if it works on the encoding side you might still end up with strange symbols.

Comment: I was eventually able to run the test program on the XP machine (seems there is an issue with static linking). It executes fine, but the console output is not showing most of the more complicated UTF-8 characters. If just displaying the characters is the problem or also conversion failed I can not say...