g_print() fails to print UTF8 string
According to documentation g_print() is supposed to receive UTF8 string and print it. But it does print garbage. The simple printf() prints text correctly.
#include <glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  guchar val[] = "яблоко";
  g_print("Fruit is %s\n", val);
  printf("Fruit is %s\n", val);

  printf("sizeof(val)=%ld\n", sizeof(val));
  for(int idx=0; val[idx]; idx++) {
     printf("%02x ", val[idx]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}

The output is:
Fruit is ??????
Fruit is яблоко
sizeof(val)=13
d1 8f d0 b1 d0 bb d0 be d0 ba d0 be

The last two line shows that val array really does have UTF8 string.
Why g_print() prints garbage? What am I missing?

All that documentation says is the format is UTF-8.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/43927373/26993270

On my case (windows 11, msys2 mingw64), I had to go through this answer's instructions to allow setlocale to work as expected (before it only returned null). So, you must call setlocale and change your current charset to utf8, only then it should print what you're expecting it to. The explanation for why it happens and why you have to use setlocale is also in here. I didn't test @user202311's route, so I don't know if it works.

Minor: printf("sizeof(val)=%ld\n", sizeof(val)); more correct as printf("sizeof(val)=%zu\n", sizeof(val));

Found a solution, not sure if it is correct one, but it works for me right now.
Apparently, the g_print() does convert UTF8 symbols into question marks if it believes that console is not UTF8 compatible: https://docs.gtk.org/glib/warnings.html#encoding
And yes, using setlocale() did solve my problem. Still, not entirely sure why.
Adding to the previous sample this code
  const char *charset;
  g_get_console_charset(&charset);
  g_print("charset = %s\n", charset);

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  g_get_console_charset(&charset);
  g_print("charset = %s\n", charset);

Provided additional output:
charset = ANSI_X3.4-1968
charset = UTF-8

So, my application, at the start, believes that console is using ANSI_X3.4-1968 code page. No idea where this came from. But setlocale(LC_ALL,"") did reset the console expectation to UTF8 - after that g_print() start working properly (and printf() continue to work properly.

I was about to ask him what locale was he using for his terminal output (probably not UTF)
