# How can I output these symbols in c++

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to output this face
all I see is question mark symbols

```
void win(){

        cout << "░░░░█▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
        cout << "░░░░█▒▒▄▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀▀▀▀▀▀▄" << endl;
        cout << "░░▄▀▒▒▒▄█████▄▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▄█████▄▒█" << endl;
        cout << "░█▒▒▒▒▐██▄████▌▒█▒▒▒▒▒█▒▐██▄████▌▒█" << endl;
        cout << "▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀█████▀▒▒█▒░▄▒▄█▒▒▀█████▀▒▒▒█" << endl;
        cout << "▒▒▐▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒█▒░▒▒▀▒▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
        cout << "▒▌▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▄▀▒░▒▄█▄█▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌" << endl;
        cout << "▒▌▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▄▒▒█▌▌▌▌▌█▄▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐" << endl;
        cout << "▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▀███▀▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌" << endl;
        cout << "▀▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
        cout << "▀▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀" << endl;
        cout << "▒▒▀▄▒▀▄▀▀▀▄▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▀░░░░▀▀▀▀▀▀" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Is your terminal capable of displaying unicode symbols?

Comment: I don't know how can I find out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++, cout and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953847/c-cout-and-utf-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows, the following code works as long as:

- The console font supports the characters.  I'm using Consolas font.
- The source is compiled from source saved in an encoding that supports the characters. Saving as `UTF-8 w/ BOM` convinces many Windows applications that a file is UTF-8, but also check your compiler for source encoding options.

Note the use of  `wcout` and wide strings (`L"..."`).  Also, `_setmode` is used to alter stdout to support UTF-16 output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

void win(){

    wcout << L"░░░░█▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
    wcout << L"░░░░█▒▒▄▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀▀▀▀▀▀▄" << endl;
    wcout << L"░░▄▀▒▒▒▄█████▄▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▄█████▄▒█" << endl;
    wcout << L"░█▒▒▒▒▐██▄████▌▒█▒▒▒▒▒█▒▐██▄████▌▒█" << endl;
    wcout << L"▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀█████▀▒▒█▒░▄▒▄█▒▒▀█████▀▒▒▒█" << endl;
    wcout << L"▒▒▐▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒█▒░▒▒▀▒▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
    wcout << L"▒▌▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▄▀▒░▒▄█▄█▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌" << endl;
    wcout << L"▒▌▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▄▒▒█▌▌▌▌▌█▄▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐" << endl;
    wcout << L"▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▀███▀▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌" << endl;
    wcout << L"▀▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
    wcout << L"▀▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀" << endl;
    wcout << L"▒▒▀▄▒▀▄▀▀▀▄▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▀░░░░▀▀▀▀▀▀" << endl;
}

int main(){
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    win();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: Console screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using windows or an unix based system (macos/linux), because windows does not use utf8 by default like macos and linux.

On macos (which i am using) your code compiles an runs completely fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void win(){

    cout << "░░░░█▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
    cout << "░░░░█▒▒▄▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀▀▀▀▀▀▄" << endl;
    cout << "░░▄▀▒▒▒▄█████▄▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▄█████▄▒█" << endl;
    cout << "░█▒▒▒▒▐██▄████▌▒█▒▒▒▒▒█▒▐██▄████▌▒█" << endl;
    cout << "▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀█████▀▒▒█▒░▄▒▄█▒▒▀█████▀▒▒▒█" << endl;
    cout << "▒▒▐▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒█▒░▒▒▀▒▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
    cout << "▒▌▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▄▀▒░▒▄█▄█▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌" << endl;
    cout << "▒▌▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▄▒▒█▌▌▌▌▌█▄▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐" << endl;
    cout << "▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▀███▀▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌" << endl;
    cout << "▀▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█" << endl;
    cout << "▀▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀" << endl;
    cout << "▒▒▀▄▒▀▄▀▀▀▄▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▀░░░░▀▀▀▀▀▀" << endl;
}

int main(){
    win();
    return 0;
}
```

and gives the desired output:

```
░░░░█▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█
░░░░█▒▒▄▀▀▀▀▀▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀▀▀▀▀▀▄
░░▄▀▒▒▒▄█████▄▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▄█████▄▒█
░█▒▒▒▒▐██▄████▌▒█▒▒▒▒▒█▒▐██▄████▌▒█
▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▀█████▀▒▒█▒░▄▒▄█▒▒▀█████▀▒▒▒█
▒▒▐▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒█▒░▒▒▀▒▒█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█
▒▌▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▄▀▒░▒▄█▄█▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌
▒▌▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▄▒▒█▌▌▌▌▌█▄▀▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐
▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▀███▀▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌
▀▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█
▀▄▒▀▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▐▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▄▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▄▄▀
▒▒▀▄▒▀▄▀▀▀▄▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▀░░░░▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

but on windows it prints:

```
????????????????????????????
???????????????????????????????
??????????????????????????????????
????????????????????????????????????
```

and so on.

So i think the problem lies in the fact the machine/terminal you are using does not support unicode.
A solution could be to use std::wcout which is for "wide" characters an example could be this:

```
std::wcout << L"█" << std::endl;
```

Or using utf16:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void win(){
    cout << "\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588" << endl;
    cout << "\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2584\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2584\u2584\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2584\u2584\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2584" << endl;
    cout << "\u2591\u2591\u2584\u2580\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2584\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2584\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2584\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2584\u2592\u2588" << endl;
    cout << "\u2591\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2590\u2588\u2588\u2584\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u258C\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2590\u2588\u2588\u2584\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u258C\u2592\u2588" << endl;
    cout << "\u2580\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2580\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2580\u2592\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2591\u2584\u2592\u2584\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2580\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2580\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588" << endl;
    cout << "\u2592\u2592\u2590\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2591\u2592\u2592\u2580\u2592\u2592\u2588\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588" << endl;
    cout << "\u2592\u258C\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2584\u2580\u2592\u2591\u2592\u2584\u2588\u2584\u2588\u2584\u2592\u2580\u2584\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u258C" << endl;
    cout << "\u2592\u258C\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2591\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2580\u2584\u2592\u2592\u2588\u258C\u258C\u258C\u258C\u258C\u2588\u2584\u2580\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2590" << endl; 
    cout << "\u2592\u2590\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u258C\u2592\u2592\u2580\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2580\u2592\u258C\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u258C" << endl;
    cout << "\u2580\u2580\u2584\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u258C\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2590\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2588" << endl;
    cout << "\u2580\u2584\u2592\u2580\u2584\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2590\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2592\u2584\u2584\u2580" << endl;
    cout << "\u2592\u2592\u2580\u2584\u2592\u2580\u2584\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2584\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2584\u2580\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2591\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580\u2580" << endl; 
}

int main(){
    win();
}
```

But again if your terminal does not support Unicode there is No way to print it.

Comment: I tried it but it did't work and nothing appears on the screen

Comment: No, I didn't use utf16 how can I try it ?

Comment: utf16 is basicly uft8 but in a hex format like \u0061 if the same as "a".  there are many converts online who convert utf8 symbols into uft16 hex format

Answer (score 0):

Try [`SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp)